# What is the difference between generative and structural recursion?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

What is the difference between generative and structural recursion in Racket?

Comment: See [How does structural recursion differ from generative recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268749/how-does-structural-recursion-differ-from-generative-recursion) or [Generative and accumulative recursion](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs135/handouts/11-genrec-post.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structural recursion happens when the "sub-problems" match up exactly with the possible pieces of the data.

For example, processing a list `lox`. The trivial case is when `lox` is empty. Otherwise the first sub-problem is dealing with the `(first lox)`, and the second sub-problem is dealing with the `(rest lox)`. You solve each sub-problem by calling a helper function, and you combine the solutions.

```
(define (process-list-of-x lox)
  (cond
    ;; trivial case
    [(empty? lox) ...]
    [(cons? lox)
     ; combine the solutions
     (...
      ; solve the first sub-problem
      (process-x (first lox))         ; data-def tells you what the first sub-problem is
      ...
      ; solve the second sub-problem
      (process-list-of-x (rest lox))  ; data-def tells you what the second sub-problem is
      ...)]))
```

What's different is that structural recursion tells you what the sub-problems are, where in generative recursion the sub-problems could be anything. You often need a new idea for how to break it up. A Eureka moment specific to the problem, not the data.

```
(define (solve-problem prob)
  (cond
    ;; trivial case
    [(trival-problem? prob) (... prob ...)]
    [else
     ; combine the solutions
     (...
      ; solve the first sub-problem
      (solve-problem (generate-first-sub-problem prob))   ; you have to figure this out
      ...
      ; solve the second sub-problem
      (solve-problem (generate-second-sub-problem prob))  ; data-def doesn't tell you how
      ...)]))
```

Also, structural recursion guarantees that it terminates because the sub-problems come from breaking up the data. In generative recursion the sub-problems can be more complicated, so you need some other way of figuring out whether it terminates.

Comment: Thank you. Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442587?noredirect=1) example be a generative recursion?

Comment: No, the code in that answer uses structural recursion plus an accumulator. It's harder to see because there are multiple inputs being processed together. Each "sub-problem" is a piece directly from the data definition, not something else from a generative idea.

Comment: interesting – I haven't seen recursion distinguished in this way. Would you consider streams a form of *generative* recursion?

Comment: Sort-of. The natural recursive call isn't really on a sub-piece of a data, but on something else, generated by the data. However, it's still easier to design than most generative recursion because the data still tells you what the sub-problems are.